# Create index to optimize search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I need help to solve the issue.

I have 20000000 records/documents in my MongoDB .  The collection has 3 keys. I am searching the collection based on 2 keys. The value of the 2 keys can be of 7 types. I am getting the search results but it is taking lot of time. I need to optimize the search using indexing.

Please suggest me what kind of index I will use to get optimum results during the search.

For e.g. 3 keys and values  can be {pid: 10 , qid: 20 , aid:30}

I need to search based on qid and aid. The qid and aid can have any combination in numbers. Like this I have 20000000 documents. I need to search for e.g. 7 find() queries with 7 different combination of qid and aid values . How do I achieve using indexing so that I get all the results from MongoDB in optimize way.

Any suggestion will be appreciated ..

Comment: We really can't help without seeing your query.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/ ?

Comment: Also, note that if each of your two keys has 7 different values, you only have 49 possible queries, which means each query returns an average of about 408000 documents. Piping this all back to your program (especially over a network) may take a long time independent of how fast the database can find all the matching results using an index.